# How can I stop automatic indenting of numbered lists, on Outlook Web App?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Lars Peterson asked for Outlook web app (outlook.office.com):

> Recently, my Outlook (online 365 Exchange) is automatically indenting new message when I type a 1. as though it is a numbered list.
>
> I do not want it to indent.
>
> When I click the stop indenting button on message format at the bottom, it either erases my number, or does not un-indent it!
>
> How can I turn OFF automatic formatting on numbered lists??

Is Vanessa Ouyang MSFT's [answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-stop-automatic-indenting-of-numbered-lists/b8496d1d-b315-4948-ac33-3c7a4025836a) dated Aug. 16 2017 still correct? Any advances since then?

> From my test and experience, it is not achiveable [sic] to disable the automatically list feature in OWA. You can share your feedback via the following link:
>
> https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/313228--outlook-on-the-web-office-365. Many features came directly from customers' feedback. As a temporary workaround, don't type space after 1. It means you can enter "1." rather than "1. ". In this way, the system will not automatically number list.

I illustrate this difficulty:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation has no changed. This is the expected behavior in OWA and I am not aware of a method to stop this. As a workaround, press Ctrl + Z to cancel the auto-formatting action.